# how to enable both script to write log to the same path

Tags: shell, io-redirection, exec

We have the two scripts `father.bash` and `son.bash`, where `father.bash` runs `son.bash` as

```
/tmp/son.bash
```

In `father.bash` we set

```
exec > $log 2>&1
```

and also in `son.bash` we set

```
exec > $log 2>&1
```

so both scripts need to write to `$log` at same time.

But this doesn't work as expected: when the `son` script is running, its output covers what is written by `father`, and vice versa.

So my question is, how to enable both scripts to write to a log file at the same path?

Comment: I think you should use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: why redirect in son bash? if not explicitely redirected, it would go to the same log as father.bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the redirection separately in `son.sh`. It will inherit the redirection set in `father.sh` when it is started by `father.sh`.